# WCF Service: Perform work after returning

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have a method in a WCF service I'm currently developing in which I would like to do some work after I have returned the result to the user.

The users of the service are sending in "items" that we store in the database and then process by calling other services and other stuff that might take a lot of time (several minutes). The thing is that the users really only need to know the database ID of the item.

So I don't want the users to wait for all that stuff to be done. Would it be a reasonable solution to start a System.Threading.Tasks.Task to perform the heavy lifting like this just before I return like this:

```
int id = InsertIntoDB(item);
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => HeavyProcessing());
return id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this option is fine. Are you having any problems with it?

Another option would be to simply make the call on the client side asynchronously, then the server implementation can be synchronous as well, but that depends on your scenario - this option is simpler to implement (no asynchrony), but it may make the server hit some of the usage quotas (such as max concurrent clients).

Comment: The applications (a whole bunch of them) on the client side are already in place, so that is not really an option, and the faster the clients' get the IDs the better, so a server side solution is desirable.

Answer (score 2):

How important is it for this task to finish succesfully? An IIS hosted WCF service can be agressively killed by IIS, and in that case that background thread can be stopped half way executing. If this is a problem, you'd be better of queuing the operation in a message queue and let a Windows Service pick it up when it comes available. Windows Services are much more reliable in that case.

Comment: That's an interesting point. Since we're currently doing all the processing in the service method we're already affected by this problem, so I guess that we'll be able to live with it as for now, but next version will probably involve a service.

Comment: For your vNext, take a look at this article. You migjt find it interesting: http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95